# Confused on float and integers, how to make the output exactly as it is, not round up or unnecessary ".0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, decimal

I'm trying to make a code to find the gradient of a straight line for my assignment.

It went well but unfortunately it didn't pass 3 test case because the output has decimals so it rounds up the decimals to make it a whole number.
This the code;

```
Ax, Ay = input ().split()
Bx, By = input ().split()
Ax=int (Ax)
Ay=int (Ay)
Bx=int (Bx)
By=int (By)
M=(By-Ay)//(Bx-Ax)
print (M)
```

input(stdln)
-10, 7,
2, 4,

your output

-2

expected output
-1.75

but when I make it a float it'll add unnecessary ".0" to whole numbers which will fail test case

```
Ax, Ay = input ().split()
Bx, By = input ().split()
Ax=float (Ax)
Ay=float (Ay)
Bx=float (Bx)
By=float (By)
M=(By-Ay)/(Bx-Ax)
print (M)
```

input(stdln)
-4, 0,
0, 20,

your output
5.0

expected output
5

Answer (score 1):

you could do a little check before printing. if the result is equal to the integer of result, then it is an integer, else float.

```py
Ax, Ay = input().split()
Bx, By = input().split()
Ax = float(Ax)
Ay = float(Ay)
Bx = float(Bx)
By = float(By)
M = (By-Ay)/(Bx-Ax)

M = int(M) if M==int(M) else float(M)
print(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make arithmetic operations on a float in python, your result will also be a float type.
If you want to remove the decimals on your result and make it an integer, simply use the int() function.

```
M=int((By-Ay)/(Bx-Ax))
```

This converts your result to an integer type and gets rid of the decimals.